# Angular Unit Test for localStorage in if else condition

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jestjs, jasmine

I start learn angular espacially in unit test. I have case where I need create unit test for localStorage. This is the code in **component.ts** :

```
   getRandomColor() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('randomColor') === null) {
      const colorCode = '7608952EAFCDBE';
      this.backgroundColor = '#';
      for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        this.backgroundColor += colorCode[Math.floor(Math.random() * 12)];
      }
      localStorage.setItem('randomColor', this.backgroundColor)
      return this.backgroundColor;
    } else {
      this.backgroundColor = localStorage.getItem('randomColor');
    }
  }
```

In **`spec.ts`**, I write like this

```
    it('getRandomColor if localStorage randomColor is null', () => {
      const spyLocalStorage = spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem').andCallFake(function (key) {
        spyLocalStorage = null
        expect(component.backgroundColor).toEqual('#')
         
      });
```

But it show error. What is the best way for this case? Your help really mindful for me. Thank you
})

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't write expectations inside the mock function, that is meant to return intended values(conditionally "andCallFake" or unconditionally "andReturnValue" not pretty sure about the apis you could refer the documentation for that) only.

1. First you've to mock all the APIs which are used inside the targeted function.
2. Then call the actual method which you want to test.
3. Then write assertions/expectations to verify the results like below.

```js
it('getRandomColor if localStorage randomColor is null', () => {
  const setItem = spyOn(localStorage, 'setItem');
  spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem').andCallFake(() => null);

  const result = component.getRandomColor();

  expect(result).toMatch(/^#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}$/);
  expect(component.backgroundColor).toEqual(result);
  expect(setItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith('randomColor', result);
});
```